# Can I use the same foreignkey more than once?

Tags: django-models

I have a table of clients and a table for events. The client is a FK in the events table. A user would select which client they are at on a particular day. I want my events table to have the fields Sunday, Monday, ....., Saturday so the user just has to select a client from a drop down list.

I've tried setting up my models like this but it didn't work when trying to migrate:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Event(models.Model):
    week = models.DateField(blank=False)
    sunday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    monday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tuesday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wednesday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thursday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friday= models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    saturday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I know of this way to allow choices as an example:

```
position = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=POS_CHOICES)
```

But i want to use choices from my table "client" instead of hardcoding the choices.

Answer (score 0):

Have to just use "related_name":

```
class Event(models.Model):
week = models.DateField(blank=False)
sunday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sunday', null=True)
monday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='monday', default=0)
tuesday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tuesday', default=0)
wednesday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wednesday', default=0)
thursday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='thursday', default=0)
friday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friday', default=0)
saturday = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='saturday', null=True)
```